# How To Initialize An Array Using Multiple Text Files - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

**Trying to create a loop to open each .txt file in the active workbook folder, to be able to pull data out of each .txt file.**

(Data from .txt files will be used for initializing an array)

---

Current code I created gives Compile error `Invalid Use of Property` for line of code:
 `folder2 = ActiveWorkbook.path`

I know that `folder2` is defined as a `Folder` data type, and thus assigning the string `ActiveWorkbook.path` variable (to find current working folder location) is most likely causing the problem.

**What would be the correct method of going through all the .txt files in the active workbook folder (or correct method of referencing the workbook folder path)?**

---

Reference:
[How to import all text files from a folder](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/649666-how-import-all-text-files-column-wise-folder.html)

---

Code snippet with problems:

```
' Loop thru all files in the folder
    folder = ActiveWorkbook.path

    path = folder & "\*.txt"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    folder2 = ActiveWorkbook.path

    For Each file In folder.Files

        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
```

Full Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Initialize_barcode_lookup_Array()

 Dim fso As FileSystemObject
 Dim folder As String, path As String, count_txt_files As Long, Filename As String
 Dim folder2 As folder
 Dim file As file
 Dim FileText As TextStream
 Dim TextLine As String
 Dim Items() As String
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
 Dim cl As Range

 Dim shipping_plan As Long      'Number of shipping plans text files imported
 Dim barcode_lookup() As String
 Dim lastRow As Long
 Dim longest_lastRow As Long
 Dim counter As Long
 Dim FNSKU_Input As String


    'Count the number of files in working directory ( - 1, for the Excel spreadsheet)
        folder = ActiveWorkbook.path

        path = folder & "\*.txt"

        Filename = Dir(path)

        Do While Filename <> ""
            count_txt_files = count_txt_files + 1
                Filename = Dir()
        Loop

        'Range("Q8").Value = count
        MsgBox count_txt_files & " : files found in folder"


    'Define longest_lastRow
    longest_lastRow = 0

    'Define i
    i = 0

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    folder = ActiveWorkbook.path

    path = folder & "\*.txt"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    folder2 = ActiveWorkbook.path 'fso.GetFolder("D:\YourDirectory\")

    For Each file In folder.Files

        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        'Define lastRow
        lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row   'Last row of the data set

           'Make sure longest_lastRow is the largest value found of lastRow within all _
           'shipping plan .txt files
           If lastRow > longest_lastRow Then longest_lastRow = lastRow

        'Redimension Array barcode_lookup()
        ReDim barcode_lookup(count_txt_files - 1, longest_lastRow, 9)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
            cl = TextLine

            'Initialize Array
                For j = 0 To (lastRow - 1) 'UBound(barcode_lookup(lastRow - 1))
                    For k = 0 To 9
                        barcode_lookup(i, j, k) = cl
                        cl = cl.Offset(0, k + 1).Value
                    Next k
                    'Set cl one row down, and set column back to 0
                    cl = cl.Offset(j + 1, k - 9)
                Next j
        Loop

        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close

        i = i + 1
    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder2 = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the GetFolder command to pick up a folder:

```
set folder2 = fso.getfolder(ActiveWorkbook.path)
```

Since it is an object variable, you need the Set command.

(Also note that folder is a reserved name in FSO, so you might want to use a different variable name just to avoid confusion and possible errors.)

Comment: Thanks vacip, I am beginning to understand how fso.getfolder() works a bit better. That part of code works, but getting an error now, 19 lines below, for the code snippet 'cl = TextLine'. Trying to read up on how to fix it- any suggestions by any chance?

Comment: Pretty sure I need to break up the text file into an array, looks like it's text-tab delimited. Currently trying to modify my code to use the technique in this guide: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-text-files

Comment: How can I make the loop only open .txt files? (Currently it's also opening the excel file I'm working from)

Comment: cl is a range, and you never set it. Use something like `Set cl=range("A1")`. _Then_ you can go and give it a value: `cl.Value=TextLine`.

Comment: To break up a string into multiple substrings, use the `Split` command.

Comment: And finally, to open only text files, check the file before opening it. Something like `If file.Type=` whatever. You know, if you have more questions, you should start a new question. :)